# Improve performance of tracking scripts - facebook, linkedin google etc

Tags: performance, tracking, page-speed, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager setup to manage all my third party tracking scripts.
These include; LinkedIn, Facebook, Hubspot, Google Adwords/Remarketing etc.

Is there a way I can optimize the performance of these scripts, so they have less of a impact on my sites performance?

I see a 50% reduction in load times and around a 66% increase in network requests when these scripts are enabled across the site.

Comment: Which ones are actually the slow ones?    Even if they take a while to run, they should run in the background and be invisible to users.  Does it really matter if they are slow?